# I2C bit banging with Clock Stretching is not working

Tags: clock, i2c

I try to implement I2C bit banging  to communicate with OLED in PIC 18F4520. Its working fine without 'clock stretching' but if I put 'clock stretching' its not working. And also I tried with put the 'clock stretching' block before and after the ACK pulse, both are not working.whats wrong with my clock stretching??

```
void send_packet(){
    /* Soft_I2C_Start();               //Here its working fine
    Soft_I2C_Write(0x78);             
    Soft_I2C_Write(tx_packet[0]);
    Soft_I2C_Write(tx_packet[1]);    
    Soft_I2C_Stop();*/

    unsigned char i,temp=0x78;          //Slave Address with write permission
    ASDA=1;           //Start Condition
    ASCL=1;
    delay_ms(1);

    ASDA=0;  
    ASCL=0;

    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        if(temp & 0x80){
            ASDA=1;
        }
        else{
            ASDA=0;
        }

        temp=temp<<1;
        ASCL=1;
        ASCL=0;
    }

    ASCL=1;           //Acknowledgment Pulse
    ASCL=0;

    while(PORTC.RC4==0);  //Clock Stretching

    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        if(tx_packet[0] & 0x80){
            ASDA=1;
        }
        else{
            ASDA=0;
        }

        tx_packet[0]=tx_packet[0]<<1;
        ASCL=1;
        ASCL=0;
    } 

    ASCL=1;         //Acknowledgment Pulse
    ASCL=0;

    while(PORTC.RC4==0);  //Clock Stretching

    for(i=0;i<8;i++){
        if(tx_packet[1] & 0x80){
            ASDA=1;
        }
        else{
            ASDA=0;
        }

        tx_packet[1]=tx_packet[1]<<1;
        ASCL=1;
        ASCL=0;
    }

    ASCL=1;           //Acknowledgment Pulse
    ASCL=0;

    while(PORTC.RC4==0);  //Clock Stretching

    ASCL=1;  //Stop Condition
    ASDA=1; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> if((temp&0x80)==1){

temp&0x80 has two possible values, 0 and 0x80. It will never == 1.

Comment: thank you. . . I correct that error but still its not working. . .I updated the edited code

Comment: Yup its working. . . The problem is with clock stretching line. . I removed that and its working. . . But still I have doubt, whats wrong with clock stretching?